# Loading package html + resources into webview

Tags: android, webkit, webview, local, assets

I would like to know how I can display a HTML page in webview with references to relative/local images. The goal is to have the html page and all linked images contained in the android application package itself.

Where would I need to place the assets (assets directory?) and how do I reference these so they load into the webview?

Thanx!
Sven

Answer (score 28):

You can put all html and images to assets directory, like:

```
assets\html\
  index.html
  image1.png
  image2.jpg
```

All references to the images in the html file should be in form of file:// url

```
<html>
<body>
  <img src="file:///android_asset/html/image1.png">
  <img src="file:///android_asset/html/image2.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

After all, just load this HTML to WebView as usual:

```
   webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/index.html");
```

Comment: I tried using `<img src="image1.png">` instead of `<img src="file:///android_asset/html/image1.png">` and it works too.

Comment: @Pang it works because `image1.png` the url is relative to the `index.html`. In some case, it won't work.